# Winter Bash 2016: Hats are coming again soon!

Tags: discussion, hats

### It's almost time for Winter Bash 2016!

For several years now, Stack Exchange has run a holiday event called [**Winter Bash**](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)! It's a fun little event where users collect "hats" that you can wear on your avatars by doing various things (post on a certain day, get a question to a certain score, and things like that).

This year the event will start on December 19, 2016, and it'll run up to and including January 8, 2017. After that, the hats we've earned will all disappear.

Of course, if we all suddenly decided we hated hats we could opt out of the event, but that doesn't seem very likely.  So unless the community objects . . .

### Hats are coming again soon! :-)

*(**Note**: Users who don't want to see hats will be able to click a button labeled "I hate hats".)*

Comment: _Gimme an H!_...

Comment: H! ............

Comment: That button's silly! Then all us scrooges who hate hats won't get the chance to pooh pooh them and enjoy our self-indulgent curmudgeonliness. We need to see them so that we can moan about them.

Comment: "This year the event will start on December 19, 2015, and it'll run up to and including January 8, 2016." Aw, so we've already missed out :(

Comment: @pydsigner Whoopsie, lemme fix that ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Hats are nice, they warm my ears when it's cold and I like them.

**Edit:** I've now found a hat that warms my ears with **fire**. This certainly does solidify my adamant position that hats are indeed good.

Comment: It's probably also to do with posting and upvoting comments too ...

Comment: try deleting your upvoted comments and see if you get a secret hat

Comment: @Mari-LouA Nope 

Comment: You need to delete more comments, go through your old comments, and where you can delete the upvoted ones.

Comment: @Mari-LouA LOL... Meh, I guess I already have a few hats. Check out my sweet mustache.

Comment: Delete upvoted comments earns you a hat. If everyone posted three comments and if we were to all upvote each other's, many a hat would be earned. I've got mine but I'll upvote comments on meta with a very light conscience. MAYBE it's enough to delete one comment that has been upvoted ten times... maybe...

Answer (score -5):

Booh! I hate hats. Especially during the festive season.

Comment: I hate festive seasons.